# Using unixODBC in a multithreaded, concurrent setting

Tags: unixodbc

I'm going to ask and answer this question because it took me forever to figure out and I wish the answer had been here to begin with.

The problem: One long-running unixODBC query blocks all others from the same application.

The question: How does one stop this from happening.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer, in the form of a cut-and-paste comment from __handles.c -- I know, why doesn't everyone think to look there for documentation to begin with, right?

```
/*
 * use just one mutex for all the lists, this avoids any issues
 * with deadlocks, the performance issue should be minimal, if it
 * turns out to be a problem, we can readdress this
 *
 * We also have a mutex to protect the connection pooling code
 *
 * If compiled with thread support the DM allows four different
 * thread strategies
 *
 * Level 0 - Only the DM internal structures are protected
 * the driver is assumed to take care of it's self
 *
 * Level 1 - The driver is protected down to the statement level
 * each statement will be protected, and the same for the connect
 * level for connect functions, note that descriptors are considered
 * equal to statements when it comes to thread protection.
 *
 * Level 2 - The driver is protected at the connection level. only
 * one thread can be in a particular driver at one time
 *
 * Level 3 - The driver is protected at the env level, only one thing
 * at a time.
 *
 * By default the driver open connections with a lock level of 3,
 * this can be changed by adding the line
 *
 * Threading = N
 *
 * to the driver entry in odbcinst.ini, where N is the locking level
 * (0-3)
 *
 */
```

Comment: I think you missed the point. The point is that one can set the threading level explicitly to work with drivers that provide some degree of thread safety on their own. myisam has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @sclv, thanks! unixODBC documentation is shockingly sparse. :/

Answer (score 3):

Just an addition to that answer. The current release of unixODBC 2.3.0 defaults to Threading = 0, so the default now is to assume that driver are thread safe. This was a risky assumption in years past, not so much now.

Answer (score 0):

If your driver supports asynchronous functions, you can enabled it and execute time consuming functions in async mode.

No threads required at application side.